# Remove an unclassified element jQuery

Tags: jquery, html-table

Here's a weird question, I'm trying to remove an element, but the problem is, it is unclassified. The entire source code is here:

```
<table width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
 <tbody>
  <tr> 
   <td valign="top"> 
    <table width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
     <tbody>
      <tr>          
       <td id="Header_ProductDetail_ProductDetails"></td>
       <td id="Header_ProductDetail_TechSpecs"></td>
       <td id="Header_ProductDetail_ExtInfo"></td>
      </tr>
     </tbody>
    </table>
   </td>
   <td width="1" valign="bottom">&nbsp;</td>
  </tr>
 </tbody>
</table>
```

Do you see the

```
<td width="1" valign="bottom">&nbsp;</td>
```

I want that deleted, but the problem is that I do not want to do something like td[valign=bottom].remove() because that will mean the everything with a valign="bottom" will be deleted. I would rather go to the nearest element that is identified like td#Header_ProductDetail_ProductDetails add something like $('td#Header_ProductDetail_ProductDetails').parent().parent().parent().parent().closest(td).remove();
Although, I know that's crazy talk since you probably can't jump up four parents, but I don't know how else to have that removed? Does anybody know if there's a quick solution to this?

Comment: What specifies that you want to remove that element? Do you want to remove everything that contains only `&nbsp;`? Elements with `width=1`?

Comment: I'm just trying to remove that element specifically and thats it. is there a way to find a `td` with a `width=1` and `valign="bottom"` and contains an `&nbsp;` kind of like `$('td[width="1"][valign="bottom"]').contains(&nbsp;).remove();`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try filtering your results based on html content using the filter function.

```
$("td").filter(function() { return $(this).html() === '&nbsp;'; }).remove();
```

Comment: What about something like: `$('td[width="1"][valign="bottom"]').contains(&nbsp;).remove();` is that possible?

Comment: @user1090389 - I thought the same thing, but contains won't work with html content like `&nbsp;`

Comment: Would I be able to add `td[valign=bottom][width=1]` to your script?

Answer (score 0):

Depending on the specificity of your structure, you could do some of the following

```
$("td").eq(index).remove();  //Remove td of specific zero-based index
$("td").eq($("td").length-1).remove();  //Remove very last td
```

If you gave some of your parent elements classes or ids you could get pretty specific in what td you want to be selecting.